# Multithreaded Allocator

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I saw the interesting talk of Alexandrescu [allocator Is to Allocation what vector Is to Vexation](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/master/Presentations/allocator%20Is%20to%20Allocation%20what%20vector%20Is%20to%20Vexation/allocator%20Is%20to%20Allocation%20what%20vector%20Is%20to%20Vexation%20-%20Andrei%20Alexandrescu%20-%20CppCon%202015.pdf) at cpp con. And i want to discuss a few design topics how to realize his idea of an allocator in an multithreaded environment.

I found a lot of people saying:

> The allocator itself shouldn't be synchronized(overhead). Instead
>   every thread should have it's allocator

But,

**How do i assign my allocator to an thread?**

Some design proposals:

1. via a map. key = thread_id, value is allocator. But the map will grow massively over time, when the id of dead threads aren't destructed (and i see no proper way to do this)
2. Create a 'large' amount of allocator, much more than ever be needed. But if you want to have static memory allocation (stack-allocator), this is a massive waste of space.